# Correct way to use Font Awesome SCSS in a Yeoman's Angular project

Tags: gruntjs, bower, font-awesome

I created an Angular project using Yeoman's generator, and now I am trying to add the Font Awesome to the project. I installed it using Bower using

```
bower install fontawesome --save
```

then it automatically added to my `app/index.html` the following code:

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But I didn't want to use it as CSS, but as a **SCSS import** (to be able to change the URL of font files). So I deleted the above code from the HTML page and added the proper code into `app/styles/main.scss`:

```
$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
$fa-font-path: "../bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/"; // <==== here

// bower:scss
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
@import "fontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"; // <==== and here
// endbower
```

Then I run `grunt build`, but something (Grunt?) edited my files back to the original ones. The `index.html` got the `<link>` again and mine `main.scss` was kept only with the Bootstrap import.

*Ok, we are almost there.*

So I looked at the Bootstrap's `bower.json` and compared to the Font Awesome's `bower.json` and I saw the following difference:

```
// Bootstrap
"main": [
  "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss", // it's SCSS
  ...
],

// Font Awesome
"main": [
  "./css/font-awesome.css", // it's CSS
  ...
],
```

Then I found a way to properly (not sure) override the Font Awesome's bower configuration using my app's `bower.json`, and added the following code into it

```
"overrides": {
  "fontawesome": {
    "main": [
      "./scss/font-awesome.scss", // now it's SCSS
      "./fonts/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Question**: Is this the correct way to use Font Awesome as a SCSS import and avoid Grunt of changing my files when building the project? By overriding its default `"main"` property?

Answer (score 4):

Judging by your question I think you may be new to the web frontend build process. Unfortunately it can be a headache at times.

First off, note that SCSS != CSS and browsers do not know how to use SCSS. Including `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.scss">` in your HTML `<head>` tag will not work. We can enjoy the various perks of SCSS (e.g. variables, imports, etc.) during development, but to use these styles in the browser we must **transpile** SCSS into CSS (which the browser recognises).

To make developer's lives easier, it is common for seed projects (such as the one you are using) to include some kind of automated build process which includes transpiling SCSS into CSS. The build process is typically executed via a task runner, such as Grunt or Gulp. These seed projects/templates also typically include a task to inject your project's dependencies (as declared in your bower.json file) into your `index.html` automatically. A tool called `wiredep` is used to read through your `bower.json` files to determine these dependencies, in particularly, it will look for the 'main' attribute to determine which files a particular package requires. It will then inject the appropriate `<script/>` and `<link>` tags.

To explain this further, when you execute `bower -install font-aweseome --save` a few things happen:

1. The package is downloaded and added to your project (usually  to `bower_components/`).
2. An entry is added to your `bower.json` file adding the package to your project's dependencies.

Each package includes its own `bower.json` file which describes its various properties, the most important of which (after name) is `main`. You can see the `font-awesome` `bower.json` file [here](https://github.com/components/font-awesome/blob/master/bower.json). As you can see, it's `main` attribute references several files. These are the files that `wiredep` uses to determine which `<script/>` and `<link>` tags to inject into your `index.html`.

By specifying an override in your **project's** `bower.json` like this:

```
"overrides": {
  "fontawesome": {
    "main": [
      "./scss/font-awesome.scss", // now it's SCSS
      "./fonts/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

You are specifying to `wiredep` that `./scss/font-awesome.scss` and `./fonts/*` are the files required by your project, and to ignore those listed in the `font-awesome` bower.json file.

Regarding SCSS: take a look at the Sass [guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide), in particular the section on imports. The Sass `@import` lets you split your styles across several smaller SCSS files (partials) that, upon transpilation, are combined and included into a single (optionally minified) CSS file. This includes **any third party SCSS** files that you import into your `main.scss`. For example, if you imported `font-awesome.scss` into your `main.scss` file, then transpiled it into CSS, the resulting CSS file would include all styles contained within `font-awesome.scss`.

To include and customize a third party SCSS file, what I do is:

1. Specify an import in my own custom `main.scss` file.
2. Make any customizations to variables I want.
3. Transpile `main.scss` into CSS.
4. Include a `<link>` tag to the transpiled CSS file in my `index.html` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Blake! Actually I am using SCSS for some time, but this is my first project using tools like Bower and Grunt. Maybe I wasn't clear enough with my question, but the thing is: **am I correct on overwriting FontAwesome properties in my project's `bower.json`**? Because I don't want to import their CSS file separately, I want to (and I am doing this right now) generate a single CSS file which includes Bootstrap, FontAwesome and anything else that the project needs. I asked that because it looked wrong. Beginner's fear maybe :-)